# How I can ignore HibernateProxy fields from my json responses

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I'm building a rest web service using spring boot and spring data jpa so I'm creating a rest controller with a get method :

```
@GetMapping("/typeQuestionnaire/{id}")
    @ApiOperation(notes = "Return a link to retrive a questionnaire type by id",value = "Get type of questionnaire by id")
    public ResponseEntity<TypeQuestionnaire> getQuestionnaireType (@PathVariable  long id){

        TypeQuestionnaire typeQst = typeQuestionnaireRepository.getOne(id);

        return  ResponseEntity.ok(typeQst);

    }
```

This my entity :

```
    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name="TypeQuestionnaire")
    @ApiModel(description = "All detail about the questionnaire")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    public class TypeQuestionnaire {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="codeTypeQstSeq")
        @SequenceGenerator(name="codeTypeQstSeq",sequenceName="code_type_qts_id",allocationSize=1)
        private Long codeTypeQuestionnaire ;
        private String designation ;
        @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="typeQuestionnaire")
        @JsonIgnore
        private Set<Questionnaire> Questionnaires ;

    }
```

My problem is when I called my api I get HibernateProxy in the response and the @JsonIgnore not working for me :

```
   <TypeQuestionnaire.HibernateProxy.SVE5tgD0>
<codeTypeQuestionnaire>1</codeTypeQuestionnaire>
<designation>test</designation>
<questionnaires/>
</TypeQuestionnaire.HibernateProxy.SVE5tgD0>
```

Comment: Have a `EntityView` `Object` which is effectively a copy of this class with only the fields you wish to return, and return one of those from the `Controller`?  It's a fairly common practice to not return your actual db-entity from the `Controller`.

Comment: As @user2478398 sad is bad practice using repository in controller. You should create additional layer `service` what communicate with repository and return object view for your controller.

Comment: Do you use any [HibernateXModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate) module?

Comment: Yes I use the Hibernate 5 module